# Help Upgrading Apache2 using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apache-2.2

I have an old Ubuntu server (dapper) running apache 2.0.x that I need to upgrade. I want to upgrade apache to the latest version of 2.0 and not upgrade to apache 2.2.

If I do an sudo apt-get install apache2 it takes me all the way up to 2.2.4 which I don't want. I'd like to stay on 2.0.x but upgrade to the most up to date version.

How can I do this using apt-get?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Stable Ubuntu repositories do **not** change major versions of packages.  Dapper has been on 2.0.55 since the day it was released.  Security fixes are patched in to the old versions instead of wholesale upgrading to new releases, avoiding potential bugs from new features.

As you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/web/apache2), the current version of the apache2 package (and supporting worker/common packages) for dapper is `2.0.55-4ubuntu2.12`.

You likely have a non-standard package repository that's providing that package.  Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.